# how to display and input chinese (and other non-ASCII) character in r console?

Tags: r

My system: win7 ultimate 64 english version + r-3.1(64) .
Here is my sessionInfo.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252     
LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C      
LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

1.can't input chinese character into r console
When I input a chinese character in r console, it turns to garbled character .

[image]
[image]

2.can't display  chinese character  on the r console
When I read data in r console, the chinese character turns into a garbled character .
You can download the data, and test it with

```
read.table("r1.csv",sep=",")
```

[Download Data](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1hqklUfU)

[image]

Please see the  graph to download the data if you don't know how to get the data from my web.

[image]

How can I setup my pc to properly display and input chinese characters in r console?
I have  updated the chinese language pack ,and  enabled it,but problem remains still.

Comment: Can you post the output of `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

Comment: put it into the text of original question  already.

Comment: Do you have East Asian language support enabled in Windows?

Comment: So, I'd like to download the csv file but I don't read Chinese and don't know what to click on in the link.

Comment: Rolf, @RichardScriven

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is probably not very well documented, but you want to use `setlocale` in order to use Chinese. And the method applies to many other languages as well. The solution is not obvious as the official document of [`setlocale`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/locales.html) didn't specifically mentioned it as a method to solve the display issues.

```
> print('ÊÔÊÔ') #试试, meaning let's give it a shot in Chinese
[1] "ÊÔÊÔ" #won't show up correctly
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"
> Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "chs") #cht for traditional Chinese, etc.
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Chinese_People's Republic of China.936;LC_CTYPE=Chinese_People's Republic of China.936;LC_MONETARY=Chinese_People's Republic of China.936;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Chinese_People's Republic of China.936"
> print('试试')
[1] "试试"
> read.table("c:/CHS.txt",sep=" ") #Chinese: the 1st record/observation
  V1   V2  V3 V4  V5   V6
1 122 第一 122 条 122 记录
```

If you just want to change the display encoding, without changing other aspects of locales, use `LC_CTYPE` instead of `LC_ALL`:

```
> Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_CTYPE", locale = "chs")
[1] "Chinese_People's Republic of China.936"
> print('试试')
[1] "试试"
```

Now, of course this only applies to the official `R` console. If you use other IDE's, such as the very popular `RStudio`, you don't need to do this at all to be able to type and display Chinese, even if you didn't have the Chinese locale loaded.

## Migrate some useful stuff from the following comments:

If the data still fails to show up correctly, the we should also look into the issue of the file encoding. If the file is `UTF-8` encoded, tither `data <- read.table("you_file", sep=',', fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM", header=TRUE)` or `fileEncoding="UTF-8"` will do, depends on which encoding it really has.

But you may want to stay away from `UTF-BOM` as it is not recommended: [What's different between UTF-8 and UTF-8 without BOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom)

Comment: can i wirte it into a configuration file?

Comment: Yep, it is called **startup file**, see this: http://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html

Comment: With your permission. May I suggest change the title to `...chinese (and other non-ASCII) character in r console?`, the issue is not really Chinese specific and others may benefit from it as well.

Comment: a last problem  about the post : if the data file (http://pan.baidu.com/s/1hqklUfU) is in the form of ansi,chinese character can be displayed properly,if data file is saved as the form of utf, same read.table command can not display the chinese character ,it is a garbled character. please resave the data file in the form of utf-8 with notepad,and try `read.table("r1.csv",sep=",")`.how can i do then if the data file is utf8 form?

Comment: You can change all the data files with notepad in the form of ansi,and open it in r with read.table, is there  a  another way to do ?

Comment: No, you don't have to. Try either `data <- read.table("you_file", sep=',', fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM", header=TRUE)` or `fileEncoding="UTF-8"`, depends on which encoding it really has. Also, you may find **notepad++** to be better than **windows notepad**. **notepad++** shows the encoding in the status bar and converts encodings easily (from Encoding menu).

Comment: I tried set locale but it does not work. I have a chinese win 10 and chinese r.base. still, not print chinese when it is in R studio