# R not recognizing Chinese characters

Tags: r

I have this saved as a script in RStudio:

```
a <- "中文"
print(a)
```

When I run it I get this error:

```
Error in source("C:/Users/Rafael/Desktop/test.R", encoding = "UTF-8",  : 
  C:/Users/Rafael/Desktop/test.R:21:6: unexpected INCOMPLETE_STRING
20: 
21: a <- "
         ^
In addition: Warning message:
In readLines(file, warn = FALSE) :
  invalid input found on input connection 'C:/Users/Rafael/Desktop/test.R'
```

This is the sessionInfo():

```
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.3
```

Edit: This only happens when I run using the Source button on RStudio, if I highlight the block of text and select Run, then the problem does not persist.

Comment: That runs with no error on my machine. Try restarting R, and if that doesn't work, provide `sessionInfo()`

Comment: Added `sessionInfo()`

Comment: I get the same error.  If you run the two lines from the console, it works as expected.  If you `source` it without specifying the encoding, it reads the file, runs, but prints `ä¸­æ–‡` instead.  As far as I can tell, RStudio saves the script in `UTF-8`.  Very odd.

Comment: Please take a look at [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/209786848-Chinese-support-in-Rstudio-on-Mac-OS) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24473681/how-to-display-and-input-chinese-and-other-non-ascii-character-in-r-console)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to display and input chinese (and other non-ASCII) character in r console?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24473681/how-to-display-and-input-chinese-and-other-non-ascii-character-in-r-console)

Comment: I get no error using `source` either, even without specifying encoding. Neither in RStudio (Ctrl+Shift+S nor "Source" button) nor in terminal.

Comment: what happens if you run with `verbose = TRUE`

Comment: Added to the top of the file, no change

Comment: Exactly facing the same problem here. I don't think any answer/comment here solves the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a Windows/UTF-8 encoding problem.  It works if you use `eval(parse('test.R', encoding = 'UTF-8'))` instead of `source()`.